# Convert For Loop to Parallel.For for data comparison not working

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, parallel.for

I'm creating a fingerprint verification application by reading the fingerprint from a standalone reader and comparing them with template from database.The reader come with build-in SDK for ease of verifying the fingerprint is matching or not.

Using normal Loop statement,be either For Each or For Next,or even Queue & Dequeue(which is not a Loop, of course),there is no issue of getting the correct owner of the captured fingerprint.Everything is just fine.

But when I was trying to convert the process to Parallel.For, it seems like failed to 'find' the correct owner of the captured template,or simply it won't able to do the matching process.

```
'normal Loop through DataTable, working fine
'Capfpstr is the captured fingerprint from reader
'Zkfp.VerFingerFromStr is a build-in SDK function

Dtc = DataTable.Rows.Count.ToString
For i As Integer = 0 To Dtc - 1
    Dbuserid = DataTable.Rows(i)(1) 'user id column           
    Dbfp = DataTable.Rows(i)(15) 'fingerprint template column
    Dbfpstr = Convert.ToBase64String(Dbfp, 0, Dbfp.Length)
    Userfound = Zkfp.VerFingerFromStr(Dbfpstr, Capfpstr, True, False)      
    If Userfound = True Then
        FrmMAIN.LblUSER.Text = Dbuserid.ToString
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

'Parallel.For won't able to find the user id
'Capfpstr is the captured fingerprint from reader
'Zkfp.VerFingerFromStr is a build-in SDK function

Dtc = DataTable.Rows.Count.ToString
Parallel.For(0, Dtc, Sub(i)
      Dbuserid = DataTable.Rows(i)(1) 'user id column                                      
      Dbfp = DataTable.Rows(i)(15) 'fingerprint template column
      Dbfpstr = Convert.ToBase64String(Dbfp, 0, Dbfp.Length)
      Userfound = Zkfp.VerFingerFromStr(Dbfpstr, Capfpstr, True, False)                                         
      If Userfound = True Then
          FrmMAIN.LblUSER.Text = Dbuserid.ToString
          Exit Sub
      End If
      End Sub)
```

Normal Loop able to find the Dbuserid,while Parallel.For unable to find the Dbuserid.
Not sure is it due to syntax error.Anyone are welcomed to highlight out.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The use of `Exit Sub` in the second code snippet is useless and no at all equivalent to the use of `Exit For` in the first code snippet.  All that does is exit that specific iteration at that point, but it was going to end right after anyway.  It does nothing to prevent more iterations being called for no purpose.  You need to look at the overloads that involve a `ParallelLoopState` and call its `Break` method when you find a match.

Comment: As a note, you can just use `If Userfound Then ...`

Answer (score 0):

The code in your `If` statement is referring to the default instance of `FrmMAIN`.  Default instances are thread-specific.  Each iteration of your parallel loop is executed on a different thread.  That means that each iteration is referring to a different instance of `FrmMAIN`, none of which is the one you're looking at.

One option for a solution is to assign the result to a variable inside the loop and then display that variable's value after the loop, where the code is being executed on the UI thread again.

To be clear, the code to "find" the value is working perfectly.  You're just displaying the result on a form that you haven't displayed.  You need to display the result on the right form.